# [ROS2] Making rclcpp::Publisher a template class

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to do that? Like

```
template <typename T>
class CustomerPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
   ...
   typename rclcpp::Publisher<T>::SharedPtr publisher_;
}
```

I tried it and instantiate a `CustomerPublisher<std_msgs::msg::String>`. It is able to compile, but got the following error

```
...undefined reference to `CustomerPublisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> > >::publish(std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >)'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328302/%5Bros2%5D-making-rclcpp::publisher-a-template-class/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering myself: Do the function definition in .hpp works.

---

Originally posted by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) with karma: 112 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1